# Soviet funding for Communists

Tags: russian-federation, democracy, soviet-union, funding

[Russia has spent over $300 million on influencing foreign elections since 2014, US officials say](https://edition.cnn.com/2022/09/13/politics/russia-foreign-elections-influence/index.html)

How does this amount compare with the money that the USSR spent on supporting various communist parties and left-wing movements? In particular, how much was spent on undermining western democracies/influencing elections (i.e., separately from the funding of various rebel movements, like [PKK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurdistan_Workers%27_Party), or the third-world communist parties, like [Mandela's South African Communist party](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_African_Communist_Party).)

Comment: I rather doubt there would research that tries to split the Soviet funding along those lines. I know the one did by Chinese on Mao's revolution-export efforts does not slice it like that.

Comment: @Fizz What I mean is the funding that went to "western" countries vs. the "third world" - I would be really surprised, if there are no data by country or even by the recipient.

Comment: Yeah, there would probably be data like that. But they also funded the Red Army Faction etc. IIRC, so not all support for the Western movements was for peaceful ones. (Apparently it was just the Stasi that trained RAF though.)

Comment: @Fizz overall amounts would be good already. If by country and/or by year - even more interesting.

Comment: Much easier to find data like that for Eastern Europe though https://www.jstor.org/stable/27752387 I suspect there weren't readily available figures for covert support.

Comment: In Western nations that didn't have communist party rule, I would think that the funding would be part of covert foreign intelligence budgets and not easily severable or available to the public.

Comment: @ohwilleke Note that the same is true about the data published by CNN. However, I suspect that much information was declassified after the collapse of the USSR - both by Russia and Western countries (which surveyed the communist activities.)

Comment: @ohwilleke: I tried to look up the overall Comintern and Cominform budgets (back when they existed), but I couldn't find them... although data does seem to exists, e.g. I found how much they spent in specific years for specific countries. One problem I've read is that Westerners weren't/aren't give access to some index files of the Soviet archives, so it's hard to ask for the relevant materials.

Answer (score 4):

I finally managed to find the full Comintern budget for one year... 1922: approx 3 million gold rubles, i.e. $1.4 million ($19.1 million in 2012 dollars.) That's pretty ancient info, and when the USSR didn't have a lot of dough to spend. But it's rather comparable per year with the Putin era, oddly enough. There are some details there per country, e.g. (in 2012 figures) Germany received $3.3 million in 1922, the US $2.1 million, Czechoslovakia, $1.3 million, the UK $1 million, and Italy likewise.

The Comintern budged varied a bit over time, e.g. went to 4 million gold rubles by 1925, but dropped to 1.3 million by 1938. (No $ equivalents for those provided in the source.)

Ref: the book *Secret Cables of the Comintern, 1933-1943*, Yale University Press. (Yeah, despite the title, the full Comintern budget info is for an even older year.)

Comment: I admit that it is not specified in the OP, but Cold War era data seem of more interest here. Still +1 is merited.

Answer (score 2):

Soviet Union provided huge help for the ruling communist parties all over the world, even if they were only partially consolidated. From 1970 to 1980 the Soviet Union spent some [$6.5 billion](https://www.csmonitor.com/1983/0104/010435.html) in economic and military aid on its non-European client states like Cuba, Mongolia, Ethiopia, Angola, Afghanistan, Mozambique, South Yemen, Kampuchea, Laos, and North Korea. Soviet aid accounted for the whole quarter of the Cuba's gross domestic product.

This source gives no data on how much have been spent on the attempts to manipulate elections and the like in developed capitalistic countries. The possibilities of using billions there may have been limited.

Comment: I think that's per year. And the estimates vary more widely e.g. some others [give](https://www.jstor.org/stable/27752387) $20 billion/year by the 1980s, although there are some disputes whether the USSR needs to have been (virtually) charged back for the larger armies that the Warsaw Pact had to maintain, mainly for the benefit off the USSR.

Comment: This is interesting (+1), however the question is more about the funding given to western countries.